# Internships - What studios should I be looking at?

Tags: internships, studio

Hey guys, 
I was wondering if you had any suggestions to which sound studios I should be looking into for an internship during the summer? Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks

Jessey

Comment: Open comment to all SSD users: What's up with the rash of down votes lately? They are frustrating to new (and established) users and really shouldn't be used unless there is a blatantly "off" question or comment. I see this particular question as perfectly acceptable. Please reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

I will mention the best way to get into games or film is through the bottom up, regardless if you have training/education or not.

Get on game developer forums, engine forums, and programmer forums - post your stuff out there for people to see. You will get a response if what you have to offer is substantial.

Same with films.

Work over the internet with dropbox and ftp.

Pick a good team/director to work with who has their stuff together and utilizes a clear and organized team with a goal in mind, vision to complete, and a good attitude towards all of its team members - you'll go further than you would with just and internship and land a better/bigger gig in the end somewhere you would want to be, and not somewhere you feel like you have to be.

Most likely, it will be unpaid. Except for the payoff at the end.

Comment: <----------- imo

Answer (score 0):

Jessey,

It would help if we knew which country you're either in or looking at.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Well duh, that was definitely a slip-up on my part...the U.S....primarily in California to be even more specific...thanks for the help!

Jessey

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get into game audio... there is a recent audio intern opening at SCEA http://bit.ly/fbBDfZ